# Stop VC++ from documenting third party code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, documentation-generation, xml-documentation

I'm including SDL in my project. For some reason VC++ 2010 `/doc` also generates documentation for the SDL headers giving me a ton of warnings about *badly-formed XML*. e.g

```
warning C4635: XML document comment applied to 'SDL_keysym': badly-formed XML: Whitespace is not allowed at this location.
```

Now I want VC++ to only document *my* code and headers. Is there someway to do this?